# Can't see hard disks

Tags: hard-drive

I'm running alpine 3.2.0 installed on a thumb drive. once I boot my linux box using the usb, I can't see my hard disks, despite having two of them installed. when I run `df -h` or `df -a`, i can't see where they are mounted in the file system. Please note that am booting from a flash drive. Please help

Comment: Please provide the output of 'df -h' and 'sudo fdisk -l'

Comment: You have 2 HDs /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. On each there are 2 partitions, so you have /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2, all marked as linux partitions.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Moreover, you should post text, not pictures for terminal output.

Comment: 'sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt' to mount and
'sudo umount /mnt' to unmount the partition again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df` shows *mounted filesystems*, not hard disks. To see your hard disks, use `parted`, `fdisk` or `lsblk`. Once you have identified

- your disks,
- their partitions, and
- the filesystems in the partitions

you may `mount` the filesystems somewhere (that is, mount each filesystem on a directory) and then `df` will show them. It is not usual for a Linux system to mount hard-disk-based filesystems automatically.

Edit: See Mercy Flicker's comment for the complete details of how the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried all your suggestions and I added some to them and it worked. i had to first make a file system to each of the hard disks by running `mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1` and secondly ran `mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /mnt`. This got my mounting working. I had also to edit my fstab file to make them mount automatic at bootup by adding my hardisks to the fstab file.