# How to save files from applications to external hard drives?

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a two part matter for clarification. I have an external hard disk drive with two partitions. Each time I shut down the machine and start I have to mount the partitions.

(1) How do I configure it so that the partitions are **automatically** mounted on each boot?

(2) How do I make the partitions accessible to be able to save directly to them from applications? At present I can't navigate to them from application menus or set file paths for example for a video capture location. However, I can open them via the File Manager to drag and drop or copy files.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change permissions on external drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74806/how-can-i-change-permissions-on-external-drives)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please [search](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=automount+external+drive) this site for similar questions and answers. If these answers do not provide the clarification you seek, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244930/edit) your question and add more details on where you need more clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically mounting USB drives on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892359/automatically-mounting-usb-drives-on-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are answers related to this question already

   - here https://askubuntu.com/a/375319/1088769
   - and here https://askubuntu.com/a/165462/1088769

   Basically using the GUI method you use the disks or gnome-disks program to mount the drive on startup. On the command line you edit `/etc/fstab` with a line that looks something like this

   ```
   UUID=<uuid> <pathtomount> <filesystem> defaults 0 0
   ```
2. For me, the path to the external drives is `/media/user_name/drive_identifier`. I am able to go there after mounting the drives. Alternatively you could mount the drives to a different designated folder and access them there.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. S. The first link solved all my problems. I wasn't aware of the graphical Disk utility and it made things really easy.